# Rainfall program not accepted in codeLab

Tags: java

I am working on an assignment from MyProrammingLab:
Write a RainFall class  that has the following field:

• an array  of doubles  that stores  the rainfall for each of the 12 months of
the year (where the first index corresponds with January, the second with
February, etc.)

The class  should also have the following methods :

• a method  that returns the total rainfall for the entire year
• a method  that returns the average monthly rainfall for the year
• a method  that returns the month with the most rain as a string 
• a method  that returns the month with the least rain as a string

Demonstrate the class  in a program  that takes 12 doubles  from the user (take the 
doubles  in the order of the months of the year, the first corresponding to the 
rainfall in January, etc.). Do input validation: if the user inputs a negative
number, ignore it and continue asking them for input until  you have 12
nonnegative doubles .

Once the user has given  you all 12 doubles , create an instance of the RainFall
class  and call its methods , printing out the total rainfall, the average
monthly rainfall, the month with the most rain, and the month with the least
rain, each on a separate line.

Here is my program, which is working fine with netbeans but rejected by codeLab:

```
import java.text.DateFormatSymbols;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class RainFall {
    final private double[] rainFall;

    public RainFall(double[] arr) {
        rainFall = arr;
    }    
    public double getTotalRain() {
        double total = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<rainFall.length;i++)
            total = total + rainFall[i];
        return total;
    }
    public double getAverageRain() {
        double average = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<rainFall.length;i++)
            average = average + rainFall[i];
        return average/rainFall.length;
    }
    public String getHighestRain() {
        int j=0;
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
            if(rainFall[i]>rainFall[j])
                j=i;
        return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[j];
    }
    public String getLowestRain() {
        int j=1;
        for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
            if(rainFall[i]<rainFall[j])
                j=i;
        return new DateFormatSymbols().getMonths()[j];
    }    

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);


        double[] rainfallInput = new double[12];
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++) {
            System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + i + ":");
            rainfallInput[i-1]=myScan.nextDouble();
            myScan.nextLine();
            if(rainfallInput[i-1]<0) {
                System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + i + :");
                rainfallInput[i-1]=myScan.nextDouble();
                myScan.nextLine();
            }
        }        
        RainFall rain = new RainFall(rainfallInput);
        System.out.println(rain.getTotalRain());
        System.out.println(rain.getAverageRain());
        System.out.println(rain.getHighestRain());
        System.out.println(rain.getLowestRain());
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated!
Thank you in advance

Comment: Add specific details on why it was rejected?

Comment: "if the user inputs a negative number, ignore it and continue asking them for input until" - You only repeat the prompt once, not indefinitely until a positive value is entered

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming your answer is rejected because you can eventually input a negative number at the second `rainfallInput[i-1]=myScan.nextDouble();`

Try with a do-while loop instead to continuously ask for a positive number.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner myScan = new Scanner(System.in);
    double[] rainfallInput = new double[12];

    for (int i = 0; i < 12; i++) {
        double input;

        do {
            System.out.print("Enter rainfall for month " + (i + 1) + ":");
            input = myScan.nextDouble();
            myScan.nextLine();

            // Optionally tell why you are repeating input
            /*
            if (input <= 0) {
                System.out.println("You must enter a positive value");
            }
            */
        } while (input <= 0);

        rainfallInput[i] = input;
    }
    RainFall rain = new RainFall(rainfallInput);
    System.out.println(rain.getTotalRain());
    System.out.println(rain.getAverageRain());
    System.out.println(rain.getHighestRain());
    System.out.println(rain.getLowestRain());
}

public double getTotalRain() {
    double total = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rainFall.length; i++) {
        total += rainFall[i];
    }
    return total;
}

public double getAverageRain() {
    return getTotalRain() / (1.0 * rainFall.length);
}

public String getHighestRain() {
    double max = Double.MIN_VALUE;
    int maxIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rainFall.length; i++) {
        double amount = rainFall[i];
        if (amount > max) {
            max = amount;
            maxIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths()[maxIndex];
}

public String getLowestRain() {
    double min = Double.MAX_VALUE;
    int minIndex = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < rainFall.length; i++) {
        double amount = rainFall[i];
        if (amount < min) {
            min = amount;
            minIndex = i;
        }
    }
    return DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getMonths()[minIndex];
}
```

Comment: I guess you are right! but it is still rejected and the only explanation that I get is : Logical error(s).

Comment: Hmm. Probably one of your min/max functions is wrong. I updated with the rest.

Comment: Thank you for your quick help really!

Comment: I tried it but still nothing, but now I get something like the output should be like:

Comment: Enter·rainfall·for·month·1:Enter·rainfall·for·month·2:Enter·rainfall·for·month·3:Enter·rainfall·for·month·4:Enter·rainfall·for·month·5:Enter·rainfall·for·month·6:Enter·rainfall·for·month·7:Enter·rainfall·for·month·8:Enter·rainfall·for·month·9:Enter·rainfall·for·month·10:Enter·rainfall·for·month·11:Enter·rainfall·for·month·12:41.88↵
3.49↵
July↵
April↵

Comment: Kind of something on the same line, not that user enter a value and click enter, looks like once the value for a month is entered, it should automatically prompt the enter next value. Is that feasable?

Comment: You have to press Enter for the Scanner to accept the input

Comment: That's what I know! Thank you for your help! I will submit it like this to the instuctor and see what he says.

Answer (score 0):

Get rid of `myScan.nextLine();` in the `for` loop and code lab will accept it.